# Create User defined function with case statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a UDF to convert a string from a column into a date. I have one column (last_time_received_services) where the period is mentioned as a string. I can successfully convert it into a date with the following case statement. How can I write this case statement into a function so that I can apply this function to the entire column?

```
case 
        when last_time_received_services like 'Jan-%' then  cast(('20' + (right(last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'01'+ '-' +'01' as date) --1
        when last_time_received_services like 'Feb-%' then  cast(('20' + (right(last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'02'+ '-' +'01' as date)--2
        when last_time_received_services like 'Mar-%' then  cast(('20' + (right(last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'03'+ '-' +'01'as date) --3
        when last_time_received_services like 'Apr-%' then  cast(('20' + (right(last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'04'+ '-' +'01' as date)--4
        when last_time_received_services like 'May-%' then  cast(('20' + (right(last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'05'+ '-' +'01' as date)--5
        when last_time_received_services like 'Jun-%' then  cast(('20' + (right(last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'06'+ '-' +'01' as date)--6
        when last_time_received_services like 'Jul-%' then  cast(('20' + (right(last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'07'+ '-' +'01' as date)--7
        when last_time_received_services like 'Aug-%' then  cast(('20' + (right(last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'08'+ '-' +'01' as date)--8
        when last_time_received_services like 'Sep-%' then  cast(('20' + (right(last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'09'+ '-' +'01' as date)--9
        when last_time_received_services like 'Oct-%' then  cast(('20' + (right(last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'10'+ '-' +'01' as date)--10
        when last_time_received_services like 'Nov-%' then  cast(('20' + (right(last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'11'+ '-' +'01' as date)--11
        when last_time_received_services like 'Dec-%' then  cast(('20' + (right(last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'12'+ '-' +'01' as date)--12
        --Quarterly Payments
        when last_time_received_services like '%- March%' then  cast(('20' + (right(last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'03'+ '-' +'01'as date) --3
        when last_time_received_services like '%- June%' then  cast(('20' + (right(last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'06'+ '-' +'01' as date)--6
        when last_time_received_services like '%- September%' then  cast(('20' + (right(last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'09'+ '-' +'01'as date) --9
        when last_time_received_services like '%- December%' then  cast(('20' + (right(last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'12'+ '-' +'01' as date)--12
        else ''
    end  as converted_last_service_date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think use can create a Scalar-valued Functions

```
CREATE FUNCTION ConvertStringToDate
(   
    @last_time_received_services NVARCHAR(150)
)
RETURNS DATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @dateResult DATE
    select @dateResult =
    case 
        when @last_time_received_services like 'Jan-%' then  cast(('20' + (right(@last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'01'+ '-' +'01' as date) --1
        when @last_time_received_services like 'Feb-%' then  cast(('20' + (right(@last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'02'+ '-' +'01' as date)--2
        when @last_time_received_services like 'Mar-%' then  cast(('20' + (right(@last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'03'+ '-' +'01'as date) --3
        when @last_time_received_services like 'Apr-%' then  cast(('20' + (right(@last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'04'+ '-' +'01' as date)--4
        when @last_time_received_services like 'May-%' then  cast(('20' + (right(@last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'05'+ '-' +'01' as date)--5
        when @last_time_received_services like 'Jun-%' then  cast(('20' + (right(@last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'06'+ '-' +'01' as date)--6
        when @last_time_received_services like 'Jul-%' then  cast(('20' + (right(@last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'07'+ '-' +'01' as date)--7
        when @last_time_received_services like 'Aug-%' then  cast(('20' + (right(@last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'08'+ '-' +'01' as date)--8
        when @last_time_received_services like 'Sep-%' then  cast(('20' + (right(@last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'09'+ '-' +'01' as date)--9
        when @last_time_received_services like 'Oct-%' then  cast(('20' + (right(@last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'10'+ '-' +'01' as date)--10
        when @last_time_received_services like 'Nov-%' then  cast(('20' + (right(@last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'11'+ '-' +'01' as date)--11
        when @last_time_received_services like 'Dec-%' then  cast(('20' + (right(@last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'12'+ '-' +'01' as date)--12
        --Quarterly Payments
        when @last_time_received_services like '%- March%' then  cast(('20' + (right(@last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'03'+ '-' +'01'as date) --3
        when @last_time_received_services like '%- June%' then  cast(('20' + (right(@last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'06'+ '-' +'01' as date)--6
        when @last_time_received_services like '%- September%' then  cast(('20' + (right(@last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'09'+ '-' +'01'as date) --9
        when @last_time_received_services like '%- December%' then  cast(('20' + (right(@last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'12'+ '-' +'01' as date)--12
        else ''
    end 

    RETURN @dateResult

END
GO
```

Use it in your query like

```
SELECT dbo.ConvertStringToDate(last_time_received_services)
FROM your_table
```

Comment: Scalar functions are just so bad for performance. At least until they finally get the inline function logic sorted out. That isn't going to be until the next release though. :(

Comment: That's it! Thank you for your answer!!

Comment: Can you explain why a scalar function is better than the inline table valued function? It may come down to how you are trying use this.

Comment: I think he simple want to convert the data with SELECT, so Scalar functions  will be used.

Comment: Looking at his example a scalar is not what they want.

Comment: About performance, I think with this simple logic, it will not impact so much to the whole query.

Comment: How do you know? What if there is a million rows in the table? The performance is going to suck horribly. The point I am trying to make is that a scalar function is NOT the right mechanism for a select statement. It is like saying, "well I know I could do it better but this is good enough". Why be complacent with mediocre?

Comment: I totally agreed with you about that. Performance is really important but I would say it is not everything. If I know about my data and as well as it not impact to my performance, I would go with Scalar function, because it makes my code simple and easy to read. Otherwise I will go with better solution like yours.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you would want to make this an inline table valued function and not a scalar function. It is pretty simple to turn this into a function. Instead of a column you need a parameter.

```
create function ConvertMyDate
(
    @last_time_received_services varchar(100) --or whatever is appropriate
) returns table as return

    select 
        case 
            when @last_time_received_services like 'Jan-%' then  cast(('20' + (right(@last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'01'+ '-' +'01' as date) --1
            when @last_time_received_services like 'Feb-%' then  cast(('20' + (right(@last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'02'+ '-' +'01' as date)--2
            when @last_time_received_services like 'Mar-%' then  cast(('20' + (right(@last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'03'+ '-' +'01'as date) --3
            when @last_time_received_services like 'Apr-%' then  cast(('20' + (right(@last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'04'+ '-' +'01' as date)--4
            when @last_time_received_services like 'May-%' then  cast(('20' + (right(@last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'05'+ '-' +'01' as date)--5
            when @last_time_received_services like 'Jun-%' then  cast(('20' + (right(@last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'06'+ '-' +'01' as date)--6
            when @last_time_received_services like 'Jul-%' then  cast(('20' + (right(@last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'07'+ '-' +'01' as date)--7
            when @last_time_received_services like 'Aug-%' then  cast(('20' + (right(@last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'08'+ '-' +'01' as date)--8
            when @last_time_received_services like 'Sep-%' then  cast(('20' + (right(@last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'09'+ '-' +'01' as date)--9
            when @last_time_received_services like 'Oct-%' then  cast(('20' + (right(@last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'10'+ '-' +'01' as date)--10
            when @last_time_received_services like 'Nov-%' then  cast(('20' + (right(@last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'11'+ '-' +'01' as date)--11
            when @last_time_received_services like 'Dec-%' then  cast(('20' + (right(@last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'12'+ '-' +'01' as date)--12
            --Quarterly Payments
            when @last_time_received_services like '%- March%' then  cast(('20' + (right(@last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'03'+ '-' +'01'as date) --3
            when @last_time_received_services like '%- June%' then  cast(('20' + (right(@last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'06'+ '-' +'01' as date)--6
            when @last_time_received_services like '%- September%' then  cast(('20' + (right(@last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'09'+ '-' +'01'as date) --9
            when @last_time_received_services like '%- December%' then  cast(('20' + (right(@last_time_received_services,2))) + '-' +'12'+ '-' +'01' as date)--12
            else ''
        end  as converted_last_service_date
GO
```

To demonstrate how to use an inline table valued function you need to do something like this. The performance gain from an inline table valued function is staggering.

```
select t,*
    , f.converted_last_service_date
from table1 as t
cross apply [dbo].[ConvertMyDate](t.last_time_received_services) as f
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The function was created successfully but if I run it on this one column (last_time_received_services) I get this error message: "Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.ConvertMyDate", or the name is ambiguous."

Comment: What do you mean when you run it on one column? Can you share the code you tried?

Comment: Edward's code solves the problem because I think I wanted to use it as a scalar function. This is what I ran: select *,[dbo].[ConvertMyDate](last_time_received_services) from table1

Comment: You don't want a scalar function for that.

Comment: How I can make it work as an inline table valued function

Comment: Works well! Thank you!

Comment: You should definitely check out the execution plan between using the inline table valued function and the scalar function. You will notice a huge difference in performance as the row count increases.